# Right analogue of xmalloc in C++

Tags: c++

Two simple questions: In plain `C` we frequently use `xmalloc` which is a allocate-or-abort routine. I implemented it in C++. Is this a right exception-free implementation?

```
template <typename T>
T *xnew(const size_t n)
{
    T *p = new (std::nothrow) T[n];
    if (p == nullptr)
    {
        cerr << "Not enough memory\n";
        abort();
    }
    return p;
}

int main()
{
    int *p = xnew<int>(5000000000LL);
}
```

Second question, if I remove the `<int>` from the `xnew<int>(5000000000LL);` call, compiler (g++ 4.7.2) **cannot infere** that `[T = int]` anymore although the return type `int *` is still there. Why is that?

**Edit:** Isn't there any overhead when using the `new` version which could throw exception even if it's not thrown? I really don't want to use any exceptions when not absolutely necessary.

Comment: `new` will throw `bad_alloc` is it can't allocate which it turn will terminate your program if you don't catch it. Which is precesiley what you want. Why do you need to do all this??

Comment: How would the compiler know that the return type is `int*` if you haven't told it what type you want to instantiate the template with?

Comment: I can understand why you are doing it. Your implementation seems fine. Your second question seems a little strange, because obviously, you need to provide the template type for the compiler to infer any typing.

Comment: Also, the compiler shouldn't infer the type, regardless of your return parameter being int. It could be that you made an error in your code, so the compiler is suggesting it is an error. I would rather the compiler done that, than happily inferring willy nilly.

Comment: Note that the default implementation of `new(nothrow)` is supposed to call the ordinary operator new, catch the exception and return a NULL pointer.

Comment: @BoPersson: but provided that the program hasn't overloaded/replaced the ordinary operator new, it doesn't actually have to do that, does it? "As-if" rule.

Comment: It *might* detect if operator new is replaced or not, but I wouldn't bet on that. The assumption that using `new(nothrow)` gets rid of all exception handling in the program is not entirely valid.

Comment: Sure, which version is faster is down to QOI.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I fail to see why this is necessary. `new` will throw `std::bad_alloc`
if it fails to allocate memory. If you don't handle exceptions, this
will lead to a call to `std::terminate` which effectively ends the
program and has the same behavior as `xmalloc`.

Of course, this changes when your compiler does not implement exceptions.

Comment: We don't want any (even tiny) overhead, so we would like to call the `nothrow` version.

Comment: But xmalloc has the same overhead as a `new` followed by checking the returned pointer. The exception overhead does not seem to matter to me, if your programming is going to die afterwards anyway.

Comment: @MatteoItalia In `g++` "almost no overhead" is how big? :-)

Comment: @pmr: An uncaught exception doesn't *necessarily* have the same behavior as `xmalloc`, because it might unwind the stack whereas `abort` doesn't. I dread to think how bad the code would have to be for this to matter, but then I slightly dread any code that uses `xmalloc`. Also there are some odd situations where you can't leave exceptions uncaught (e.g. callbacks from C libraries), in which case you'd have to catch it and abort *somewhere*.

Comment: @Martin: in g++ the overhead of using throwing new is that you might miss out on some optimizations in cases where the compiler could (if you'd used nothrow new) prove to its own satisfaction that a certain block of code doesn't throw.

Comment: And if you can eliminate all exceptions from your whole program, then `-fno-exceptions` would shrink the executable and apply further optimizations, and you could manually remove any code that was written solely to provide exception guarantees. But it's a very restricting choice to make, to ask for a significantly non-conforming mode. Modern C++ practices don't really allow for it, so you might find that you can't use the libraries you want to.

Comment: @SteveJessop OK, I see your point. In that case the right solution would be to provide the full set of overloads required to correctly mimic a call to new (minus no_throw) and proceed as OP did.

Answer (score 3):

> Second question, if I remove the `<int>` from the
>   `xnew<int>(5000000000LL);` call, compiler (g++ 4.7.2) cannot infere that
>   [T = int] anymore although the return type int * is still there. Why
>   is that?

Function template arguments are deduced only from the types of the argument expressions in the function call. Since `T` doesn't appear in the function parameters in any way, it cannot be deduced.

What you do with the return value of the function call doesn't affect template argument deduction in C++, ever. If you write `int *p = some_function(5000000000LL);` then `int*` *is not* necessarily the return type of `some_function`, it's a type to which the compiler will attempt to convert the return type of `some_function`.

So the proximal reason that the compiler can't deduce `int` is that the standard forbids it (at least, without a diagnostic). The ultimate reason is that the designers of C++ (probably Stroustrup originally) wanted to limit the things taken into consideration 
for deduction, to keep the rules if not simple then at least comprehensible to mortal minds.

There's a rule in C++ that the type of a sub-expression only depends on the sub-expression itself, not on the surrounding expression. And AFAIK there's only one exception, which is when a function pointer or member-function pointer is ambiguous:

```
void foo();
void foo(int);

void (*pfoo1)() = &foo; // &foo evaluates to a pointer to the void overload
void (*pfoo2)(int) = &foo; // &foo evaluates to a pointer to the int overload
void (*pfoo3)() = (void(*)(int))&foo; // &foo evaluates to the int overload, but doesn't convert to the type of pfoo3 so the line fails.
```

Comment: And both my questions are answered. Thank you very much for the neat explanation of my second question.

Answer (score 1):

This code is not guaranteed to be 100% safe because `operator<<()` **could throw**. Practically it's not widespread case because to throw there shall be some rare conditions met:

1. `std::cerr` has `badbit` set in its `exceptions()` mask (by default it's not)
2. Exception is thrown during output

In this case exception will be rethrown and memory will leak.

About removing `<int>` from template function call expression - of course it will not work. Compiler could deduce template arguments type only from call expression itself, not from lvalue type that it will be assigned. So template arguments that you want to be auto-deduced shall be function arguments, not return type:

```
template <class T> T f1();
template <class T> T f2(T);

int a = f1();   // Will not compile, shall be f1<int>();
int b = f2(42); // OK
```

Exceptions overhead actually depends on implementation. I believe modern compilers are smart enough to avoid such overhead if possible, but you shall check it with your platform to be sure.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to avoid an exception throwing `new` (for whatever reason - maybe you're working on a platform where exceptions aren't supported, like some embedded platforms), you can provide a `new_handler` to abort the program if `new` can't allocate memory:

```
#include <stdlib.h>

#include <iostream>
#include <new>

namespace {
    void new_handler_abort()
    {
        std::cerr << "Not enough memory\n";
        abort();
    }

    struct new_handler_abort_installer {

        new_handler_abort_installer() {
            std::set_new_handler(new_handler_abort);
        }

    };


    // a statically allocated object that does nothing but install the
    //  new_handler_abort() function as the new_handler

    new_handler_abort_installer install_new_handler_abort;
}
```

Merely including this source file as part of your program will install a `new_handler` that will abort the program is `new` has trouble allocating memory.

However:

- it's not deterministic when this init will be done (other than it'll happen before `main()` is called).  So if you run into memory problems before `main()`, it might not do exactly what you want.
- the compiler may still add code to support exception handling, and for some compilers that includes code that occurs on each call to `operator new` so there may still be *some* small amount of overhead spent to deal with exceptions that will never occur (newer compilers may avoid this overhead by using a table-driven stack unwind that avoids having to run code to set up exceptions on each call).